# T-SQL variable in top 3 from select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL variable defined and a select top 3 from another table with a where and order by. What I am trying to achieve is to determine whether the variable exists the values returned from the select top 3 statement. I have googled this for hours and can't seem to find a solution to what I need.

Below is what I have so far. Any help on how to achieve the desired result or even anywhere to look that will give me a direction is is much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @binVar BINARY(64)

SET @binVar = 0xD9B1E89669FF2991EA880897A45EDB68EC11E5638D09DF4DB396CF10A77E6EE940D1A1ECB86598746B1A1C0D91D7955ACFB11BFFE98D36C6FBC5CC73CBA9B158

SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM tbl2 
WHERE ID2 = (SELECT tbl1.Field1 
             FROM tbl1 
             WHERE tbl1.Field2 = @User) 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: Your variable is called `@binVar`, yet the `SET` command sets another variable `@Pass`, which is then never used in your code later on ...... this question doesn't make a whole lot of sense at all ......

Comment: xQBert, i am unable to provide exact code and variable values as it is sensitive information under UK DPA. i have tried the rubber duck method and regarding rextester it is not the coding itself i am having difficulty with but rather the logic on how to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: thank you marc_s. i have adjusted now

Comment: @JB The variable `@binVar` is still not being used in the query.

Comment: a MVCE doesn't require use of sensitive information.  It requires an example and expected results.   I for one am having trouble understanding your question.  So is binVar the same as @user?  as JB pointed out it's not used in code later...

Comment: that is the problem, i want to know if @binVar is in the list of returned values. i can't extend the where clause as that afftects the top 3 results

Comment: In which field of tbl2 there's this information?

Comment: @Joe Taras. the values are held in tbl2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016435/xqbert - an example would be if @binVar Exists In (select top 3 from ....)

Comment: @JB: The value obviously is inside tbl2 but in which field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change your `TOP 3 *` with `TOP 3 yourfield` (where this value can be present)
Try this:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN @binVar in (
       SELECT TOP 3 yourfield 
       FROM tbl2 
       WHERE ID2 = (SELECT tbl1.Field1 
         FROM tbl1 
         WHERE tbl1.Field2 = @User)
       ORDER BY ID DESC ) THEN 'EXISTS'
    ELSE 'NOT EXISTS'
END
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you Joe

Comment: @JB Have a nice day ;)

Comment: For repeatable use, you should really include an ORDER BY with the TOP statement.  Otherwise a statistics update could cause the result to change.